# JQuery .load() function stops working completely when query string is added to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a `div#Container` that includes a form. When the form is submitted, it triggers a function:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('submit','.myForm',function(){

                var a       = $(this).find(".a").val();
                var b       = $(this).find(".b").val();
                var c       = $(this).find(".c").val();
                var query   = $(this).find("input[name=query]").val();
                var body    = $(this).find("textarea[name=body]").val();

                $( "#Container" ).load( "myURL.php?" + query, 
                {
                    'a'     : a,
                    'b'     : b,
                    'c'     : c,
                    'query' : query,
                    'body'  : body

                },
                function() {
                    //callback ;
                });

            });
        });
</script>
```

`myURL.php` contains code that processes the new comment which was just submitted, and then displays all comments. If I remove the `query` and load the address `"myURL.php"` by itself, the comment is processed normally and all the comments are loaded. However when I try to add the query string to the address `"myURL.php" + query`, the new comment does still get processed, but none of the comments load. `div#Container` remains empty.

edit: the pattern of the query is

```
"player=John Smith&league=grape_fruit&description=player&owner=Minutemaid"
```

Comment: Could you give the pattern of the query. It my be the error

Comment: How are you receiving these parameters in php? Note that `load()` switches between GET and POST depending on data argument and you are actually mixing GET and POST

Comment: Post the code of myURL.php as well please

Comment: @daheda I've edited my question to include the query pattern.

@charlietfl The parameters vary based on which page they are on. They're pulled from $_GET and set as individual variables. Those variables are then assembled into a string and echoed as the "value" attribute of a hidden input on the comment form. Is it not OK to mix GET and POST in `.load` ?

Comment: You need to show us your PHP code. Have you checked your console.log to see if you get any errors? Also, check the network tab in your developer console to see the actual response of the call. Without the PHP-code, we're just guessing here.

Comment: You can mix them but you need to make sure you are using `$_POST` for the object data since it is in POST method

Comment: Btw, you're not passing the response to your callback function?

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel myURL.php is prohibitively long (about 1300 lines). It basically checks if the request is post, same domain and if the user is logged in. Then it validates the comment, enters it into a database, and retrieves all the comments for that page from the database and displays them. The comment processing part **always** works, even with the query string. However the comments are only displayed if there is no query string. In either case the comments will all display if the main page is reloaded, but I need to avoid unnecessary page reloads.

Comment: Your request is GET not POST. Do you intercept in php using POST? If yes, change it to GET.

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel  OH! So even the "a", "b " & "c" parameters that I am passing are GET variables? I thought only the query string was GET and the rest was POST.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No. That was just a placeholder when I first wrote it.

Comment: You need to show us you _actual_ code and you also need to show us the _relevant_ parts of the php-code. Without them, we can only guess, which isn't particular helpful for either you or us. We might be good, but there are limits...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that *is* the actual .load request. The only difference is i changed "csrf_token" to "a" (for example), and I replaced the player's real name with "John Smith". I can post a skeleton of myURL.php if you like.